# Ubuntu 14.04 running slow on a 64 bit processor

Tags: 14.04, performance

I upgraded from win 8.1 64 bit to Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit version. My PC have 4 GB of ram and 2.23 GHz dual core processor... after installing Ubuntu its running slow.. should I switch to 32 bit or are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have 3D acceleration, which Ubuntu needs. If 3D acceleration is not found, Ubuntu uses the CPU instead of the GPU to let appear some image on your screen. That's very CPU-intensive, so that's probably why your computer is so slow.

Also, the hardware architecture (64 bit vs 32 bit) won't matter.

You can try installing the proprietairy driver. Start the application Driver Manager and install the proprietary driver.

If that doesn't work to speed up your computer, you might want to do this:

Install Lubuntu. This does not require 3D hardware acceleration. Your computer will be amazingly fast:
http://lubuntu.net

[image: This is what Lubuntu looks like]

If you want long support, consider downloading the LTS version (long term support). That's the same as downloading 14.04.

Good luck.

Comment: Expanded my answer