# Older PC what Ubuntu do I install?

Tags: system-installation

If I have an older PC laptop, that doesn't have 2g of harddrive space, which older version should I use?

Comment: Voting to close based on previous community closes: http://askubuntu.com/questions/347091/best-ubuntu-based-distro-for-older-computer

Comment: Less than 2GB? I suppose you are talking about internal memory, not HDD.

Comment: In another thread the suggestion is Lubuntu...



 http://askubuntu.com/questions/544622/ubuntu-14-04-running-slow-on-a-64-bit-processor][2] 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/544622/ubuntu-14-04-running-slow-on-a-64-bit-processor

Comment: Too little information was given here. Please post all laptop specifications.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a more lightweight distro if your PC is old.

Go with [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/).

It's an Ubuntu official Distro without Unity but with Xfce Desktop Environment which is more lightweight.

Have a try... :)

Answer (score 0):

Another good lightweight distro for ubuntu users  is Bodhi Linux :
http://www.bodhilinux.com

With this distro, apt-get uses ubuntu repositories.

Works fine on 1st generation of asus eee-pc.

Answer (score 0):

In this computer, so little space in the hdd (only 2 gigas).

The best distribution is:

Slitaz 5.0

http://mirror.slitaz.org/iso/5.0/slitaz-5.0-rc2.iso